# Ошибка С2280 - "предпринята попытка ссылки на удаленную функцию"

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

На 53 строчке кода выдает ошибку

> Ошибка    C2280   "ProductText::ProductText(const ProductText &)": предпринята попытка ссылки на удаленную функцию.

В чем проблема?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<ctime>
#include<fstream>
#define rows 10
#define colls 10
using namespace std;
struct ProductText
{
ofstream f;
string filename;
};
 struct ProductArray
{
int *arr;
};
class IBuilder
{
int **arr;
public:
int Getter(int r, int c) { return arr[r][c]; }
IBuilder(int**arr) :arr(arr) {}
virtual void StepA() = 0;
virtual void StepB() = 0;

};
class BuilderText : public IBuilder
{
ProductText product;
public:
BuilderText(int**ar) :IBuilder(ar) {}
virtual void StepA()
{
    cout << "Ente filename";
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    product.filename = name;
}
virtual void StepB()
{
    product.f.open(product.filename, ios::out);
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < colls; c++)
            product.f << Getter(r, c) << " ";
        product.f << endl;
    }
}
ProductText GetResult() { return product; }
};
class BuilderArray :public IBuilder
{
ProductArray product;
public:
BuilderArray(int**ar) :IBuilder(ar) {}
void StepA()
{
    product.arr = new int[rows];

}
void StepB()
{
    int i = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < colls; c++)
            i += Getter(r, c);
        product.arr[r] = i;
        i = 0;
    }
}
ProductArray GetResult() { return product; }
};
class Director
{
IBuilder * builder;
public:
Director(IBuilder*builder) :builder(builder) {}
void ChangeBuilder(IBuilder*p)
{
    delete builder;
    builder = p;
}
IBuilder* make()
{
    builder->StepA();
    builder->StepB();
    return builder;

}
};

void main()
{
srand(time(NULL));
int **ar = new int*[rows];
for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    ar[r] = new int[colls];
for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < colls; c++)
    {
        ar[r][c] = rand() % 100;
        cout << ar[r][c] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
Director d(new BuilderArray(ar));
BuilderArray*p1 = static_cast<BuilderArray*> (d.make());
ProductArray pp = p1->GetResult();
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    cout << pp.arr[i] << " ";
cout << endl << endl;
d.ChangeBuilder(new BuilderText(ar));
BuilderText*p2 = static_cast<BuilderText*> (d.make());
ProductText ppp = p2->GetResult();
}
```

Comment: Вы бы привели все же компилируемый код...

Comment: @Harry пардон. привел

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что потоки не копируются.

Пытаясь вернуть `ProductText`, вы должны его копировать, а копировать `ofstream`,который он содержит - нельзя...

Компилятор так и пишет:

> "ProductText::ProductText(const ProductText &)": функция неявно удалена, так как элемент данных вызывает удаленную или недоступную функцию '"std::basic_ofstream>::basic_ofstream(const std::basic_ofstream> &)"'

Comment: Тут бы еще напомнить про std::move...